# Netbeans JDBC Error "Unable to find suitable driver" after JDK update

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans

I recently upgraded my jdk from 6 to 8 when I installed Eclispe for Android. Now, in NetBeans when I try to right click on the node for the database and select connect, I get the following error:

"Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost 1527:/Animal using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (Unable to find a suitable driver)."

So far, I have tried uninstalling Eclipse and reinstalling Netbeans and that didn't work. I'm not getting any errors in my code aside from a popup that says the project is missing resources. Could someone please provide instructions on how to  solve this issue? I've looked on the NetBeans' website and on this forum and there doesn't seem to be a clear procedure for resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

If that's not a typo on your part your JDBC URL is malformed:

```
jdbc:derby://localhost 1527:/Animal
```

That's what I copied from your question. However, the correct URL would look like

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Animal
```

With the colon before the port, not after.

At Netbeans already states that this driver was tried but failed I'm quite sure it's got nothing to do with your driver setup. But if you want todouble check:

Here's a [tutorial on how to add and enable oracle thin driver](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html). I'd think it will work the same way for derby drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Jan. I fixed the url per your suggestion and updated the database installation in the properties to point to the new glassfish version file and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in the following way:

The driver that you use to connect to the database may have deleted it or changed your address. So that:

- You must put it back in the address that was indicated in the databases driver> 
  Drivers> (driver you use to connect)
- Indicate the new address where you are

The error is in the path you are specifying in the driver or in the connection.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when trying to connect MySQL server to NetbeansIDE. Turns out the jdbc connector was an old version. [You can read about the MySQL connector versions here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html). Either

- download the latest version of MySQL connector or
- add a new driver.

My problem was solved by adding a new driver.